# Reverse Polarity Question

Tags: circuit-protection, reverse-polarity, schottky

everyone.

I have a really simple power input network like so:

[image: Schematic]

The SMPS will power analog devices with +12V and the regulator will regulate the rest downstream to power digital circuitry with +5V. Additionally, I have two sense terminals on the board that will take measurements of an attached load. The - terminal is connected to ground with everything else. This throws a wrench in my workflow with respect to reverse polarity protection at the sense terminals. If I hook up something in-between 5 and 12 volts or maybe higher on the negative side, I'm afraid my current setup wouldn't be enough and it could damage chips. Should I consider placing a barrier diode on the OUT side of the regulator as well? What are your layout recommendations in regards to protecting against a positive voltage scenario on the - sense terminal?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I've added more of the schematic for clarity.

[image]

Comment: Does your sense (-) HAVE to be connected to circuit gnd?

Comment: @KyleB In my setup the analog components use that ground as a reference for sensing and feedback loops. Is there another way to do it? I'd love to get some input.

Comment: Theres always another way ;)   Whats the nature of your sensing circuit?  Is it just an ADC and you're going straight to the inputs?  Or do you have some signal conditioning circuit first????

Comment: @KyleB Yes I am sensing the + side of the shunt resistor with a 16-bit ADC referenced to the same ground potential. Nothing fancy. I prototyped it with a smaller pcb and it gave me accurate current readings for 1 amp +/- 5%. This setup, however, will go up to 5 amps and will use 4 MOSFETS. Let me know what your thoughts are.

Comment: What are you doing with the four MOSFETs???     There's a simple schematic-drawing tool in the editor (look in the tool bar above the editing window).    A picture is worth 1000 words   ;)

Comment: @KyleB I see the tool, but I went ahead and just copy and pasted the entire MOSFET portion.

Comment: Where are the A/D inputs?????    I was most curious about how you're referencing the A/D  (-).   If that can be "floated" relative to ground, you'd be in a better place.

Comment: You might also consider something really simple, like this:  https://components101.com/articles/design-guide-pmos-mosfet-for-reverse-voltage-polarity-protection

Comment: @KyleB This is the analog circuit apart from the ADCs measuring the voltage across the resistor which are on a different page of the schematic. But could you explain or provide an article on how it is possible to measure the load voltage if it is floating and not connected to your AGND or DGND at some point? Is it by measuring a differential voltage across the resistor? Thanks. And thanks for the MOSFET protection article as well.